# Android extension file bigger than 2 GB?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk

I am trying to create an APK extension file (.obb) bigger than 2 GB. Yes, I know that in Play Store exists that limitation, [BUT in Oculus Store files up to 4 GB are allow.](https://developer.oculus.com/blog/tech-note-expansion-file-support-for-gear-vr-beta/)

However, when I try to create the "big" extension file (Using Unity 2017.1.0p5 and (Split Application Binary), the console shows the following Android error:

```
    CommandInvokationFailure: Android Asset Packaging Tool failed.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aapt.exe package -v -f -F rawobb.ap_ -A rawobb -0 "" --ignore-assets "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
stderr[ Unable to add 'rawobb\MenuMusic.tbe': Zip add failed (-2147483648)
ERROR: unable to process assets while packaging 'rawobb.ap_'
ERROR: packaging of 'rawobb.ap_' failed
]
stdout[
Found 5 custom asset files in rawobb
Configurations:
 (default)
```

Please, I would like to know how I could use aapt (and its zipping) to allow create such a big files, and then I was wondering about create perhaps a gradle task in Unity with that command.

Or if you know some other way of creating a big obb and that Unity could read it (I would like to avoid hosting files in other servers).

Many thanks!

Comment: Google Play uses 2 files that can be 2 GB each. Could be Oculus Store does the same

Comment: @Zoe No, they say that:
> Gear VR applications can now be up to 5 GB (via a 1 GB APK and 4 GB data file).
in the link that I posted before: https://developer.oculus.com/blog/tech-note-expansion-file-support-for-gear-vr-beta/

Comment: Oculus documentation in your link states that Unity has a 2GB limit: `Note that Unity's “Split Application Binary” option will only generate an expansion file up to 2 GB. For larger applications, you may want to use an asset bundle.`

Comment: @MorrisonChang Yes, agree, but because of that I was asking about Android first. Or for example, creating an 'asset bundle system' and generating "manually" and obb that Unity can read.